# Sqlite3 Db to Json, used for Highcharts?

Tags: python, json, highcharts, sqlite

I'm currently working with a database and i would like to display its values on a webpage, using highcharts.

Here is what i use to fetch the data in the web app :

```
@app.route("/data.json")
def data():
   connection = sqlite3.connect("/home/pi/database/Main_Database.db")
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   cursor.execute("SELECT epochTime, data_x from table")
   results = cursor.fetchall()
   return json.dumps(results)
```

Then i currently get this value by doing this in my html:

```
$.getJSON('http://192.168.1.xx/data.json', function (data) {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },
        title : {
            text : 'title'
        },
        series : [{
            name : 'Value',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            },   .......
```

This works if i want to display only one data array.
If i want to display more than one array, then it looks like each arrays must be preceded by its name respecting a certain parsing (i checked on the data sample used by highcharts).

Example:

```
data1:[(epochTime, 200),(epochTime,400)];data2:[(epochTime, 2),(epochTime,4)]
```

I have some trouble to `json.dumps` two arrays from two different tables for example. I tried to use this following command : `json.dumps({data1:results})`.
But the results is still not readable.

Do you have any advice ? Or example/templates of webapp/highcharts using sqlite?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Do you want to show more than one series in one chart or do you want to show multiple charts?

Comment: Hello, more than one series in one chart. Here is the kind of data i would like to get on a json.dumps ----->     

var x=[[epochtime, 1],[epochtime, 2]]; var y=[[epochtime, 1],[epochtime, 2]],etc...

I know this parsing is working, i'm not sure if other form would do the trick. However i'm a beginner and i couldn't find the proper way to do so.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle (not by me) i'm starting with. http://jsfiddle.net/mhardik/gpR9d/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

In the controller:
Fetch 2 results and put them in a dictionary.

```
@app.route("/data.json")
def data():
   connection = sqlite3.connect("/home/pi/database/Main_Database.db")
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   cursor.execute("SELECT epochTime, data_x from table")
   results1 = cursor.fetchall()
   cursor.execute("SELECT epochTime, data_x from table2")
   results2 = cursor.fetchall()
   return json.dumps({'result1': results1,
                      'result2': results2})
```

On the page:

```
$.getJSON('http://192.168.1.xx/data.json', function (data) {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },
        title : {
            text : 'title'
        },
        series : [{
            name : 'Value1',
            data : data.result1,//read result1
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            },
            {
            name : 'Value2',
            data : data.result2,//read result2
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            },   .......
```